# Out of the box JSON support in Oracle Java EE 7 JDK

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

According to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html)
there should be a JSON support in the latest Java EE JDK 7u45. However, when I installed the JDK and attached the libraries to the project (I use IDEA v12), the package javax.json still doesn't seem to be available.

Should there be an additional library installed for oracle implementation of JSON? If it shouldn't what jar file from the JDK is responsible for JSON classes implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON` support has released with `Java EE 7`, not `Jdk 7u45`. `javax.json` is the package of Java EE 7 libraries not Jdk library. To get support of `JSON` you should put `Java EE 7` libraries on your classpath. At present, Java EE 7 compatible server is Glassfish 4. So you should put Glassfish 4 libraries or use maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, Masud, Thanks for the answer. I installed Java EE 7 Development Kit Bundles with JDK. Is JSON supposed to be there?

Comment: @2late, I have update my answer. Java EE 7 sdk include Glassfish 4. You should put Glassfish 4 library or use maven.

Comment: do you know where Java EE libs are located in glassfish4 directory layout? I am more keen to solve this issue with IDEA since I really like it would prefer not to change it to other IDE.

Comment: The default location of java ee 7 jars of Windows, `C:\glassfish4\glassfish\modules`, But you should not use jar this way, best way is include server from your IDE.